# htaccess apache. How can I allow access to admin`s url via ip?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

htaccess. How can I allow access to admin`s url via ip? And disallow other ips.
For example, I want to allow acces to url site.com/admin only for few ips.

I use

```
<Directory /admin/>
Order deny, allow
deny from all
Allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 
</Directory>
```

but get error 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this condition. If request is not from your allowed IP you redirect to index.html

```
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX.XX.XXX.XX
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [R,L]
```

Comment: may I use few ip?

Comment: yes u can use it
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX.XX.XXX.XX
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^YY.YY.YYY.YY
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [R,L]